# How do I save a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have this "for" cycle I want to save it to a data frame. It can be only the products or include the punctuation. But the most important thing I need is to save the products. When I print selRepo it only stores the last product.

I need to store it in a data frame to join with other data. I got the code from this example: https://www.aprendemachinelearning.com/sistemas-de-recomendacion/

[Notebook Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YCFy.png)

```
for i, aRepo in enumerate(user0[-5:]):
    selRepo = df_prod[df_prod['prod_id']==(aRepo+1)]
    print(selRepo['productos'] , 'puntaje:', users_predictions[usuario_ver][aRepo])
```

Output:

```
25    OSADIADESODORANTE
Name: productos, dtype: object puntaje: 5.180760670067219
20    EFFECTIVESINAROMAROLLON
Name: productos, dtype: object puntaje: 5.320436472896831
32    TEMPTATIONDESODORANTE
Name: productos, dtype: object puntaje: 5.7425065576284515
17    EFFECTIVEBRISAFLORALROLLON
Name: productos, dtype: object puntaje: 5.767411510805634
30    SOYSEXYFRESHCOLOGNE
Name: productos, dtype: object puntaje: 6.437717177503803
```

Comment: you should try creating a variable and store the result in there. like python dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing value which defined inside for loop. That is why it only print the last one. After selRepo = df_prod[df_prod['prod_id']==(aRepo+1)] line you need to append that value to one predefined list. It will loop through all values and append them into one list. Then from outside of that for loop you can print and see all values or any value you want

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a python variable and store the result in there. Variable may depend on your need of data structure. In this sample , I used Dictionary.

```
# creating empty dictionary
mydata = dict() 
for i, aRepo in enumerate(user0[-5:]):
    selRepo = df_prod[df_prod['prod_id']==(aRepo+1)]
    mydata = "Store whatever output you want to store."
```

Now you can use `mydata` variable which will have all the data. For `DataFrame`, you can create new `DataFrame` and store into it ans Also you can convert dictionary to dataframe(not always a good idea, but i don't know which dataframe you are using).